# How to parse multiple lines with one regex command?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have two line that looks something like

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

To parse, I used a command like `("^Content-Type:\s(.*)")` to capture the `(text/plain)` portion. On the other hand, I used regex like `("^Content-Type:\s(.*)[;]")` to capture the same string `(text/plain)`. Is there any way that I can use one that will work in both cases? I am using python and I am new to regex. thanks

Comment: Tags should inform users about your language. I edited that in for you this time.

Comment: `^Content-Type:\s+(.*?)(?=>;|$)` although you don't need regex at all for such a simple case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just modify your Regex a bit:

```
Content-Type:\s([^;\s]*)
```

Here is a working link:  [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XdmIMV/2)

Comment: OP is trying to capture the content type string, not the whole header line: `text/plain`, not `Content-Type: text/plain`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for the `?` quantifier (6th down in the [list in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)). It will allow the trailing portion to appear once or not at all, covering both cases:

```
^Content-Type:\s+([^;]+)(?:;.*)?
```

Here are the changes I would recommend:

- Do not capture `.` in your capture group. `*` is greedy, so you *will* get undesirable characters sometimes: e.g. if you have two semicolons in the string, the first one will get captured. Instead, capture `[^;]`, which means "anything but semicolons".
- Change the quantifier in the main catpure group from `*` to `+`. You want at least one character to match, which is what `+` expresses.
- I would also add the `+` quantifier to the preceding `\s` just to be safe. It will allow you to match multiple spaces, should that ever happen.
- Make the part that matches the `;` into a non-capturing group (a group starting with `(?:`. This allows you to apply the `?` quantifier to it.

As @RudyTheHunter indirectly points out, if you use plain [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match), you don't need the leading `^` or the trailing portion after the semicolon at all since `match` looks in the beginning of the string.

You can therefore use just

```
Content-Type:\s+([^;]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've stated in the comment, regex is an overkill for such a simple match, so for the sake of completeness:

```
def parse_content_type(data):
    if data.lower()[:13] == "content-type:":  # HTTP headers are case-insensitive by spec.
        index = data.find(";")  # find the position of `;`
        return data[13:index if index > -1 else len(data)].strip()  # slice and strip

print(parse_content_type("Content-Type: text/plain"))  # text/plain
print(parse_content_type("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"))  # text/plain
```

It's more verbose but, in theory, it should be faster.